# Ajax, JavaScipt with Django, update data on page

Tags: django, ajax

I want to make an asynchronous update of the data on the page. There is a table that loads data from the database. Outputs via Django template engine, data in the table is added/updated from the side.

And so that I can see them in the table, I need to refresh the page itself. But I need the table to be updated without updating the page itself. I reviewed a lot of options and examples on the Internet, but I did not understand. There are no simple examples.

Please help, I think many people are interested in this question :slight_smile:

view.py

```
def test(request):
    
    last_3 = New_tables.objects.filter(active=0).order_by('-id')[:3]
    last_new_table = reversed(last_3) 
       
    return render(request, 'main/test.html', {"last_new_table":last_new_table})
```

test.html

That’s how I tried to output via Javascript, but unfortunately it doesn’t work either. Updates the data on the page only after the page is refreshed…

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %} {%block content%} {% load static %}

<script src="https://snipp.ru/cdn/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover table-dark">

  <thead>
    
    <tr>
      <th class="text-white-50 bg-dark" style="font-size: 0.9em;" scope="col">Table</th>
      <th class="text-white-50 bg-dark text-center " style="font-size: 0.9em;" scope="col">N</th>
      <th class="text-white-50 bg-dark text-center " style="font-size: 0.9em;" scope="col">Type</th>
      <th class="text-white-50 bg-dark text-center " style="font-size: 0.9em;" scope="col">Quote</th>
      <th class="text-white-50 bg-dark text-center " style="font-size: 0.9em;" scope="col">Start</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="tbody">

  </tbody>

</table>

  <script>

    function index() {
     
     $('.tbody').empty()
      {% for kl in last_new_table %}
      
        $(`
          <tr>
    
            <th class="text-white-50 bg-dark" scope="row">TBL000${"{{kl.id}}"}</th>
            <td class="text-warning bg-dark">${"{{kl.n}}"}</td>
            <td class="text-info bg-dark text-center">${"{{kl.instrument}}"}</td>
            <td class="text-info bg-dark text-center"><img src='{% static "down.png" %}' width="20%" height="15%"></td>
            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 0.9em;">....</td>
    
          </tr>
          `
          
          ).appendTo('.tbody')
         
      {% endfor %}
      
    }
    setInterval(index, 200)
  
  </script>


{%endblock content%}
```

how to make the data automatically loaded into the table?

above in the template I tried to connect java with an update every 0.5 sec, but it doesn't work (

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before. Follow these steps.

`views.py`

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def test(request):
    last_3 = New_tables.objects.filter(active=0).order_by('-id')[:3]
    last_new_table = reversed(last_3)
    
    data = []
    for kl in last_new_table:
        data.append({
            'id': kl.id,
            'n': kl.n,
            'instrument': kl.instrument,
        })
    
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

In your template update the code like below

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="tbody">
     <!-- the table goes here, replace the this with your code -->
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  function fetchData() {
    fetch('/url_gose_here_replace_this')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const tbody = document.querySelector('.tbody');
        tbody.innerHTML = '';
        data.forEach(kl => {
          const row = document.createElement('tr');
          row.innerHTML = `
            <td>${kl.id}</td>
            <td>${kl.n}</td>
            <td>${kl.instrument}</td>
          `;
          tbody.appendChild(row);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }

  fetchData();
</script>
```

add an endpoint to the `test` view and call that URL in here `fetch('/url_gose_here_replace_this')`. Doing this will update the content whenever a new record is added to the database and whenever the data record changes it will change in the table.